# Unable to reference to uhd(USRP)

Tags: g++, ubuntu-12.04, gnuradio, uhd

There is some linker issue while compiling a cpp program
I use g++ and ubuntu 12.04

Installed uhd from repo.
libuhd.so file is located in /usr/lib

Now my question is

1.For linking uhd I used -luhd,but that gives me an error 
undefined reference to `uhd::set_thread_priority_safe(float, bool)'

Should I add library path of libuhd to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

I did that by the command 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/libuhd.so

After this I tried compiling again but same error?
It would be great if you could help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is uhd::set_thread_priority_safe the only UHD function you are calling in your entire program?  It is strange that that is the only undefined reference you are seeing from your program.  If it is the only function in there, then it simply isn't finding the library.  If it isn't, it sounds like the UHD version you have is strange.

Have you tried doing a:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

...after adding the library path to /etc/ld.so.conf?

When you say you installed it from the repo, what repo are you referring to?  What distro are you running?